# Displaying speedometer in Final Cut Pro

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I often see a speedometer in people's videos. I have time indexed speed data, is there any way to get it into the video (as text even) in Final Cut Pro?

Data is in TCX (or GPX) but I could easily write a script to convert that to another format.

Comment: What is the format of your time indexed speed data? Have you checked out https://sites.google.com/site/verymadmart/cyclecam

Comment: @PaulZagoridis I did come across that. Current versions of the Java Runtime don't have the 32-bit processor though. It's a fair effort to set that up but may wind up being the only reasonable option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free [Dashware](http://www.dashware.net/) app, which is normally used to overlay telemetry data directly on footage.

As per the [FAQ](http://www.dashware.net/faq/),

> **What’s the best way to use DashWare with another video editor, so I can do sophisticated edits?**
>
> How to make blue/green screen, gauge-only videos with DashWare:
>
> - Add your video and data files to the DashWare project like usual: synchronize, set up your gauges how you like, etc
> - Once you are ready to export, create a new “Green Screen” gauge. In this new, empty gauge add a Filled Rectangle component with the
>   dimensions of your video (e.g. 1920 by 1080). I use a bright, neon
>   green color for the fill. You want to pick a color that you are not
>   using in any of your other gauges.
> - Put this new gauge behind all the other gauges in your project and it will cover up your source video.
> - Export and now you will have a green screen video with only gauges.
> - In your favorite video editor use a chroma key filter to turn the green screen parts of the video transparent and presto you have a
>   transparent video with your gauges.

Comment: Thanks for that but DashWare appears to be mac only. I don't see how this could work with FCP

Comment: @paullb Dashware is Windows only, but they claim it runs well under Bootcamp.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't really need FCP.

VIRB Edit for Mac software version 3.6.0
http://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=6593

Youtube instructions (for Windows but should work the same).
Add SPEEDOMETER DATA on GoPro How To Overlay Speed, RPM, GPS in Video FOR FREE

Now if your can't get your footage into VIRB for some reason, you could try to import the TCX/GPX and see if it will just output the gauges. If that doesn't work, create a chromakey video with a blank green or blue screen and import data to add the gauges. Export the video and you'll then have a chroma keyed gauges plate to drop into FCP.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this in Apple Motion using data that is formatted in the correct file format?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Motion, but every hint I've seen since posting this still uses VIRB software.